# The JavaScript cannot be opened if I click the button

Tags: javascript, html

I have written this code.

```
  document.getElementById('show').onclick = function()
```

But I tried clicking "show" and instead it does not open and it indicates me as an error.
So anyone have a solution ?

Comment: Do you have a function body (in {}) that shall be executed?

Comment: And could you provide us the error message?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null.

Comment: Then it seems to be that there is no element with the ID show. Watch into @marmeladze s answer for the correct declaration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

it's sample on w3schools

You can try it.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>This example uses the HTML DOM to assign an "onclick" event to a p element.</p>

<p id="demo">Click me.</p>

<script>
document.getElementById("demo").onclick = myFunction();

function myFunction() {
  //your codes here Zean
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "YOU CLICKED ME!";
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 document.getElementById('show'). addEventListener("click", function() {})
```

Would be the correct syntax but it really just depends what you want to do

Answer (score -1):

Try function name without the brackets

```
document.getElementById("show").onclick = function;
```

See also [addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener).